# Angularjs + MVC 4 deployment on IIS 7.5

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4, angular-ui, angular-ui-router, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using Asp.net MVC 4 and Angularjs
for JavaScript render i use Bundling , In development environment code is working fine 
i have 3 test environment only one have IIS 7.5 on that i got blow exception. on other it is working 
file.

**SCRIPT5022: [$injector:modulerr]  http://erroer.angularjs.org/1.2.19/$injector/moduleer?p0=myApp&p1=permission%20denied**

I have 2 web sites A and B 
A is using asp.net 
B is using MVC4

this are two different application when we directly brows(IIS)  B application then it is working properly and when we call from A the it gives above exception in Console.

Comment: Is that error url correct?

Comment: Yes this is copy from console

Comment: I guess we must believe the message "Permission Denied"... Which points to an IIS permission issue most likely.  I'm not sure what angular needs, most likely read, execute and write on that folder. One thing you can do is look on that server's security error log and see if you can find out the name that was rejected.